# Task Scheduler Powershell DCOM error

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler, dcom

I am running a task to execute a powershell script.

The script runs fine if I run it manually through powershell, or through the task scheduler with "Run only when user is logged on" is selected.

If I change it to "Run whether user is logged on or not" (even with highest privledges checked) I get the following error when I catch the exception from my powershell script that tries to open up internet explorer:

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF0
1-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
At D:\PSA\EYReserve\EY_reserve.ps1:14 char:18
+     $ie = New-Object <<<<  -com internetexplorer.application;
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman 
   ds.NewObjectCommand
```

I've tried steps provided in solutions for similar problems but they did not work. Namely modifying DCOM settings, adding "NETWORK SERVICE" with full permissions etc.

Anyone think of something I could have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly were the DCOM permissions modified? What permissions has the user that the script is running in been granted?

Comment: I am an administrator so I don't think that's an issue.

I granted full control to administrators. COM Security -> Edit Defaults -> Allow Local/Remote access

Comment: I don't think this is a PowerShell issue, but has to do with the change in Vista+ so that Session 0 is non-interactive. When you try to _"Run whether user is logged on or not"_, it starts in Session 0, which then doesn't let you run the interactive COMObject.